# Orthonormalization condition for $L^2$ operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, wavefunction, special-functions

This is ortho-normalization condition for eigenfunctions of square of orbital angular momentum:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^\pi d\theta\sin\theta \ Y^*_{l'm'}(\theta,\phi) Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)=\delta_{l,l'}\delta_{m',m}$$
but I can't understand why we have $\sin(\theta) $ in this relation.

Comment: See the volume element in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system

Comment: Please note that [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is the site standard for mathematical expressions.  We very strongly discourage posting images of equations (or images of text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differential solid angle (in spherical polar coordinate ) is  $$d\Omega=\sin\theta \ d\theta \  d\phi$$

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi d\Omega \ Y^*_{l'm'}(\theta,\phi) \ Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\ \sin\theta \ d\theta \  d\phi Y^*_{l'm'}(\theta,\phi) \ Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)$$

---

Note that for any general wave function $\psi(r,\theta,\phi)$, You required
$$\int_\mathcal{V}|\psi(r,\theta,\phi)|^2 dV=\int_\mathcal{V}|\psi(r,\theta,\phi)|^2 r^2dr  \ d\Omega=1$$